Logic: if the plausibility of $(A|C') > (A|C)$, explain how $(AB|C') = (AB|C)$
In Probability Theory by ET Jaynes, the author states that if the plausibility of a proposition $A$ increases when the proposition $C$ is updated:
$$
(A|C') > (A|C);
$$
but the plausibility of $B$ is unchanged:
$$
(B|AC') = (B|AC);
$$
then
$$
(AB|C') \geq (AB|C).
$$
If the plausibility of $A$ has increased, how can $(AB|C') = (AB|C)$? In other words, shouldn't the logical product $AB$ always be larger since $A$ is larger given $C'$?

Perhaps knowing that $AB,C$ occurred is equivalent to knowing that $AB,C'$ occurred.

@lulu sorry I'm having trouble understanding your explanation. Could you elaborate a bit more?

What "law of multiplication"?  These are not independent events.

Take an example.  Say you are tossing a fair die and let $A={4,5,6}$, $B={2,6}$, $C={1,6}$, $C'={4,6}$.  Then, for example, $A\cap B={6}=A\cap C= A\cap C'$ so the last condition certainly holds.

@RobertIsrael I think I'm confused about treating degrees of plausibility as real numbers. Perhaps the propositions $A$ and $B$ and their degrees of plausibility are separate things in the sense that $AB$ does not mean "the product of the real-valued plausibilities of $A$ and $B$"?

Should say:  I am thinking about "probability".  Not sure what "plausibility" means in this context.  And assumed that, e.g., $AB$ referred to the intersection, $A\cap B$.  To stress: the probability of $A\cap B$ is only equal to $P(A)\times P(B)$ if the events are independent (it's the definition of independence).

@lulu sorry, I'm using the same verbiage found in the textbook, i.e. "to each proposition about which [we] reason, [we] must assign some degree of plausibility, based on the evidence we [are] given."

Well, that's not a definition.  I'll stick to "probability".  That is, I'll define the plausibility of an event to be its probability.

@lulu I think your fair die example is really helpful. It also helps me understand independence. Maybe you can post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Can't do it now, but I will later.

@lulu in Cox approach, "plausibility" predeces probability. Plausibility is some function from propositions to real numbers satisfying some conditions (for example, $(AB) \leq (A)$, or the condition in the post), and then Cox theorem says by monotonic transformation plausibility can be transformed to probability measure. Of course, we can't calculate plausibility of $AB$ from just plausibilities of $A$ and $B$ without knowing also sometihg of their interaction.

@mihaild  Thank you.  So, to be clear, in a situation in which we have a well defined probability, we can call that the "plausibility" as well, right?   From what you write, I assume that "plausibility" is intended as a less formal version of probability...something that makes sense even in situations where we really can't quantify much.

@lulu yes. But essentially, Cox theorem says that if plausibility satisfies some "common sense" requirements, it's essentially the same as probability. In bayesian approach, it is used as justification for requirement of assigning probability to all statements.

@RobertIsrael Jaynes requires $(B|AC) = (B|AC')$, not $(B|C') = (B|C)$.

I added a link to the book referred to by the OP where the term plausibility is defined.

@mihaild thanks for clearing up some of that semantic confusion. It also helped me understand things better. So the plausibility function $(A|B)$ maps the logical propositions $A$ and $B$, whose values are either true or false, to real-valued probability measures?

@JonBehnken no, just to probabilities. Or, more precisely, plausibility is function that maps combinations of statements "$X$ given $Y$" to real numbers, and from it we can build probability measure, that also assigns real numbers to statements, but this times it respects standard probability laws (like $P(A) + P(\neg A) = 1$).

Suppose
$$
(A | C') > (A | C).
$$
Let $B$ be such that $AC'$ implies $\overline{B}$, and $AC$ also implies $\overline{B}$. In that case, we have
$$
(B | AC') = (B | AC),
$$
since both of them are impossible. But then we also have $C'$ implies $\overline{AB}$, since $A$, $B$, and $C'$ cannot be simultaneously true. Similarly, we have $C$ implies $\overline{AB}$. Therefore, as above,
$$
(AB | C') = (AB | C),
$$
since both of them are impossible.
